# AsyncTask в RxJava

Tags: android, rxjava

Здравствуйте!
Никак не могу понять, как перевести простой AsyncTask в RxJava.
Возьмем для примера:

```
private class Sync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              String proxy_arr = "";
                    try {
                        Document jsoup_proxy = Jsoup.connect(Constants.SITE_PROXY_LIST)
                                .userAgent(Constants.USER_AGENT)
                                .ignoreContentType(true)
                                .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                                .timeout(Constants.USER_TIMEOUT)
                                .get();

                        if (jsoup_proxy != null) proxy_arr = jsoup_proxy.text().trim();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        new DebugLog(getActivity(), "News", "Sync PROXY", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
              return proxy_arr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("err_internet")){
            func.toastMessage(R.string.toast_err_nointernet, "", "alert");
        }

        reloadAdapter();
    }
}
```

Как его можно перевести, в такое же рабочее состояние с RxJava?
Спасибо!

Comment: зачем переводить на RXJava, если ты не знаешь RX?)

Comment: понять принцип и отличия

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> observer) {

                if (!observer.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    String proxy_arr = "";
                    //код из doInBackground()

                    observer.onNext(proxy_arr);
                    observer.onCompleate();
                }
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // указываем поток, в котором будет работать Observable
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // указываем поток, в который будет передаваться результат из onNext
        .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(String town) {
                            //код из onPostExecute
                        }
                    });
```

[Observable.create()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html) создает новый [Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) который будет испускать данные. В эту функцию передается реализация `Observable.OnSubscribe` в котором и будет выполняться вся работа. Когда результат готов, то вызываем метод `onNext()` с полученным результатом. Далее этот результат будет передан в метод `call` объекта `Action1`.

Методы `subscribeOn()` и `observeOn()` указывают на то, в каком потоке должна происходить работа объектов `Observable.OnSubscribe` и `Action1`.

Так же к `Observable` можно добавлять различный методы, например [onErrorReturn()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html), [map()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html), [flatMap()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) и т.д. Полный список операторов можно найти в [официальной документации.](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html). Для использования `AndroidSchedulers` необходимо подключить к проекту [Android Module](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module). При использовании `rxJava` советую использовать библиотеку [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda). Она позволит использовать лямбды, ссылки на методы и некоторые другие фишки Java 8 и улучшит читаемость кода.

Так же есть хорошие статьи по этой теме на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/search/?q=%D0%93%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC).